# CMD file opens when I launch Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I have recently installed Anaconda version 4.12.0 and created a virtual environment which I launched in Spyder 5 using Python 3.6. The problem is that every time I launch Spyder, a CMD file opens simultaneously. When I try to close the CMD, Spyder also closes. What can I do to stop the CMD file appearing? I have no experience with Anaconda, so any help would be higly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Reset the configuration: File > Preferences > Configure navegator / Configure conda > Reset to defaults

Comment: Hello! I've already tried this method, and it doesn't seem to work...The CMD file is still opening..

Comment: reinstall Spyder.

Comment: the same result:/